# RxJS - How to 'pipe' an Observable's result into another subject in one stream

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables, subject, rxjs-pipeable-operators

In RxJS I sometimes come across an occasion when I have one Observable emitting, and I would like to 'trigger' another Observable's emission.

For example:

```
subject1$.subscribe(result => {/**/})

//...later 

someObservable$.subscribe(result => {
  subject1$.next(result);
});
```

I'd rather avoid two streams, but I can't work out is there's a pipable operator I can use to 'pipe' any omissions from `someObservable$` into subject1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Subject` is both an `Observable` and an `Observer`.

The `tap` operator accepts and `Observer` as its parameter.

The `subscribe` function also accepts and `Observer` as its parameter.

Putting all these things together, you may look at something like this

```
subject1$.subscribe(result => {/**/})

//...later 

someObservable$.tap(subject1$).subscribe();

// or

someObservable$.subscribe(subject1$);
```